# Custom Title Formatting

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I have the following custom subsection title formatting:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    % Raised Rule Command:
    % - arg 1 (optional) how high to raise the rule
    % - arg 2 thickness of the rule
    \newcommand{\raisedrulefill}[2][0ex]{\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}\hfill}

    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

    \titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}
    {\rule[0.3ex]{5pt}{1.5pt}
    \thesubsection\,\rule[0.3ex]{8pt}{1.5pt}\,}{0em}
    {#1\,\raisedrulefill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}}

    \begin{document}


    \section{Test}

    \subsection{This is a test tile}

    \subsection{This is a long test title that isn't formatted how I'd like it to
    be}

    \end{document}
```

Which looks as follows.

[image]

However, I'd like reformat subtitles that happen to be two lines long as follows.

[image]

So somehow the line would have to be placed relative to the center of a box which contains the title in a box (that wraps the title around).

Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an option, you can save subsection heading in `sbox` then control the width of this box, if the width exceeds a fixed length `\maxwidth` then the heading text is inserted within a parbox.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

    % Raised Rule Command:
    % - arg 1 (optional) how high to raise the rule
    % - arg 2 thickness of the rule
\newcommand{\raisedrulefill}[2][0ex]{\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}\hfill}


\def\maxwidth{.8\textwidth}

\newsavebox\tempbox

\def\testwidth#1{%
\sbox{\tempbox}{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd\tempbox<\maxwidth
    \usebox{\tempbox}%
  \else
    \parbox{\maxwidth}{#1}%
  \fi}


\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}
    {\rule[0.3ex]{5pt}{1.5pt}
    \thesubsection\,\rule[0.3ex]{8pt}{1.5pt}\,}{0em}
    {\testwidth{#1}\,\raisedrulefill[0.3ex]{1.5pt}}

\begin{document}


\section{Test}

\subsection{This is a test tile}

\subsection{This is a long test title that isn't formatted how I'd like it to
    be}

\end{document}
```